# Unable to store array in session if array size is big laravel 6

Tags: laravel

I'm using custom method to authenticating a user. While authenticating a user i'm putting some data in session. The data i'm inserting is array/object. But i'm facing a problem if the array size is more than 8. if i put 9 array data it is logging me out (having some problem with session maybe).  Can't find a reason behind this. Can anyone help me out!

this is my array/object structure.

```
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [privileges_of_role_id] => 1
        [role_id] => 4
        [institute_branch_version_id] => 1
        [is_active] => 1
    )
```

method that i'm handling to authenticating a user:

```
public function signInAction(Request $request)
{
    if (!$request->ajax()) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), array(
            'identifiers' => 'required|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|max:20'
        ));

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        }

        try {
            $loginBy = NULL;
            $loginByValue = $request->identifiers;

            if (is_numeric($loginByValue)) {
                if (strlen($loginByValue) > 3 && substr($loginByValue, 0, 3)) {
                    $loginBy = 'phone_no';
                } else {
                    $loginBy = 'user_id';
                }
            } else if (filter_var($loginByValue, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $loginBy = 'email';
            } else {
                $loginBy = 'username';
            }
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }

        $loginCredentials = array(
            $loginBy => $loginByValue,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'is_active' => 1
        );

        if (Auth::attempt($loginCredentials)) {

            $PrivilegesOfRole = DB::table('tbl_privileges_of_roles')
                ->where('role_id', Auth::user()->role_id)
                ->where('is_active', 1)
                ->take(8)  // if i take 9, its not letting me logged in.
                ->get();
            $request->session()->put('PrivilegesOfRole', $PrivilegesOfRole);


            return redirect()->intended(route('home::onlineInfo'));
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()
                ->with('errorMessage', 'The identifiers and password you entered don\'t match.')
                ->withInput();
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Invalid request!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try using a different [session driver](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/session#configuration).

Cookies have a maximum length of 4096 bytes - if you are currently using the `cookie` driver you may be bumping up against that limit.

`.env`:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```